# Why queue accepts vector as its underlying container?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, c++14

Consider the following piece of code:

```
std::queue<int, std::vector<int>> Q;
Q.push(1);
Q.push(2);
```

[<kbd>**Live Demo**</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d8db4602b22f691a)

Beside of the fact that using a container with contiguous memory as the underlying container of a `std::queue` would significantly deteriorate the queueing operations' performance, the above piece of code is perfectly acceptable and compiles. However, if we call the `std::queue::pop` member function (e.g., `Q.pop();`) the program fails to compile, and the compiler rightfully complains that `std::vector` hasn't got member function `pop_front`.

[<kbd>**Live Demo**</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1897d577db2a22d1)

**Questions:**

1. Why is `std::vector` acceptable as an underlying container for `std::queue` since it doesn't satisfy `std::queue`'s criteria?
2. Isn't some short of meta-programming magic to check whether the underlying container of `std::queue` fulfils the necessary criteria in the line of queue's definition (e.g., `std::queue<int, std::vector<int>> Q;`)?
3. Could the advent of [concepts-lite](https://isocpp.org/blog/2013/02/concepts-lite-constraining-templates-with-predicates-andrew-sutton-bjarne-s), probably in C++17, solve this problem?

Comment: By giving it a vector, you've violated its contract. It's not required to say that, but it currently *could* check for those functions.

Comment: @chris: He is obviously aware of that. He is actually asking why the code compiles and how to prevent it from doing so.

Comment: @ChristianHackl, It answers question 1; it's not acceptable, but it's not `queue`'s job to check. It also touches on 2 and 3 by saying yes, it's possible to check the functions. Seeing as how Boost has Concept Check with concept-like syntax, the SequenceContainer requirement should also be possible to check.

Comment: @chris: I had only seen the first sentence of your comment, before you edited it :)

Comment: @ChristianHackl, I have no memory of editing it O_o I'll accept that I did, though.

Comment: Somebody handed you a loaded gun. Did you have to blow your foot off? Couldn't the gun stop you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is std::vector acceptable as an underlying container for std::queue since it doesn't satisfy std::queue's criteria?

It's not.

> Isn't some short of meta-programming magic to check whether the underlying container of std::queue fulfils the necessary criteria in the line of queue's definition (e.g., `std::queue<int, std::vector<int>> Q;`)?

This sentence doesn't make sense, but if you're asking whether it's possible to diagnose this at instantiation, the answer is yes. It would largely be a waste of time, though. For comparison, note how out-of-bounds `std::vector::operator[]` is also *your* responsibility and will not result in a diagnostic.

> Could the advent of concepts-lite, probably in C++17, solve this problem?

Insomuch as it's a "problem" at all, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Theory aside: in practice, vector based queue implementations (using push_back/erase) almost always outperform list based queue implementations.

Try it yourself.

The reason this is generally the case is due to the predictability of contiguous memory access as it relates to today's CPU cache management: sequential array access is far more predictable (for cache pre-loading) than list nodes are.

Even Bjarne Stroustrup advises to try vector based solutions to lists, because, on today's hardware, they tend to do do better.